# Printing Nested Values from Firebase Query with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a firebase database structured like so:

```
Playlist
    Playlist1
        0:  "song1"
        1:  "song2"
    Playlist2
        0:  "song1"
        1:  "song2"
```

What I would like to do print the name of each playlist name onto a TableViewController. I understand how the TableView works, but what I'm hung up on is how to make the call to the database. I have hardcoded for now as

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Playlists/Playlist1")
 ref.observe(.value, with: {
            snapshot in
            print(snapshot.key)
```

This obviously isn't scalable, is there anyway I can iterate over all the data and just get the playlist names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your structure:

[image]

```
  Database.database().reference().child("Playlists").observe(.value, with: { (_snapshot) in
        if let playLists = _snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {

            var names = [String]()

            for playlist in playLists {
                names.append(playlist.key)
            }

            // return names in a completion
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
```

outputs:

[image]

I would also recommend to NOT use the name of the playlist as a key, you should use an ID like childByAutoID, it's a built in firebase method. Then, have the name as attribute.

Comment: I added a print statement inside the for loop and there was no data outputted. To your point, do you think it would be best to structure the data like                  Playlists:
    0:
        0: "song1"
        1: "song2"
        name: "Playlist1"

Comment: check new edit, I think your parent node is called 'Playlist' instead of 'Playlists'

Comment: not sequential, use childByAutoID when inserting new values.

Comment: okay, changed the parent node to 'Playlists' (kept the original structure), still no data being outputted

Comment: Thanks for the help, works great now! I think I made it hard on myself with how I structured the database initially, so I'll follow your advice

Comment: No problem! It takes a while to get used to NoSQL modeling, good luck!